# View Qt.point value while debugging QML application

Tags: javascript, debugging, qt-creator, qml, qt-quick

Ho can I view valie of point created with Qt.point() in Expression panel while debugging in Qt Creator?
Now I see only 'object' without value.
I can only debug points with console.log(point) but is is very inconveniently.

In QML/Js console, if I enter name of point variable I get 'Unimplemented command "evaluate"'

- Qt Creator 3
- Qt 5.2.0
- Windows 7 x32

Comment: GDB has an ability to install printers (written in python) for watched variables. Try adding new tag and googling this topic

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in (at least) Qt 5.2.1, added on February, 2014.
See [Error in console window: unimplemented command "evaluate"](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11516) for more details.